# How to get an entity-related object correctly

Tags: java, spring, java-8, entity, jooq

I have approximately the following entity:

```
public class Article {
    private String name;
    private Long fileId;
}
```

As you can see, it has a field `fileld` that contains the id of the associated file, which is also an entity. However, the file does not know anything about the `Article`, so the only thing that connects them is the `fileId` field in the `Article`. Therefore, they must be explicitly linked so as not to get lost. Now to get a linked file, I have to make a separate query to the database for each `Article`. That is, if I want to get a list of 10 `Article`s, I need to make a request to the database 10 times and get the file by its id. This looks very inefficient. How can this be done better? I use `jooq`, so I can't use `JPA`, so I can't substitute a file object instead of the `fileId` field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make an assumption that your underlying tables are something like this:

```sql
create table file (
  id      bigint primary key
  content blob
);
create table article (
  name    text,
  file_id bigint references file
);
```

In case of which you can fetch all 10 files into memory using a single query like this:

```java
Result<?> result =
ctx.select()
   .from(ARTICLE)
   .join(FILE).on(ARTICLE.FILE_ID.eq(FILE.ID))
   .fetch();
```